# 'No Data' under search appearance for 6 week old site

Tags: google-search-console

All other fields, such as queries, pages, devices, etc have been populated with data for weeks, but search appearance only provides me with a statement of 'no data'. Even if I haven't optimized structured data yet, shouldn't my page titles and meta descriptions be rendered under search appearance? What possible causes are there? Thanks.